# Python - How to click button on site?

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver

How do I click a button on this page? It is modified by some javascript script which I am unable to login through. Someone can help?

link: [LINK TO TARGET PAGE](https://www.oglaszamy24.pl/logowanie)

```
driver.get("https://www.oglaszamy24.pl/logowanie")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='email']").send_keys('aaa')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pass']").send_keys('bbb')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("javascript:ab_close(1)")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginsubmit']").click()
time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working fine, tested , i think you need to maximize window.
and I have taken the locators as id as they are directly available for username and password.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\User1\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.oglaszamy24.pl/logowanie")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys('aaa')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys('aaa')
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("javascript:ab_close(1)")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginsubmit']").click()
time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some js  may help , even thought you don't know  it . It's simple and you can do it like that :

> wd.execute_script(""" document.getElementById('email').value == 'aaa' """)

the problem of that , is that if you want to change your email value , you need to change it in the code .